# is it possible not to make class from maven dependencies as final

Tags: java, maven, dll, final, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to extend class build by Maven from dependencies, however it is added as final class.

I have to build jar with .dll libraries as resources. The code for loading them is not written by me and is included to project as Maven dependency. I have trouble with loading those libs. In IntelliJ I added path to .dll libs to project structure. When I run code as IntelliJ class, all is working.

The problem begins, when I want to run packed jar. I use maven-assembly-plugin. It is working (all dependencies are loaded), however I still cannot load these libs.

I have come up with an idea to overwrite class responsible for finding these libs by myself, however they are as final class and I cannot extends them.

Is it possible to change it signature?

Part of class responsible for loading libs:

```
public final class Hub {
private static final File TEMP_DIRECTORY_LOCATION = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
private long nativeHandle;
private final String applicationIdentifier;

public Hub() {
    this("");
}

public Hub(String applicationIdentifier) {
    this.applicationIdentifier = applicationIdentifier;
    loadJniResources();
    initialize(applicationIdentifier);
}


private final void loadJniResources() {
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (osName.contains("mac")) {
        boolean wasLoadSuccessful = loadOSXResourceFromSysPath();
        if (!wasLoadSuccessful) {
            wasLoadSuccessful = copyAndLoadOSXFromTemp();
            if (!wasLoadSuccessful) {
                throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError("Could Not Load myo and myo-java libs");
            }
        }

    } else if (osName.contains("win")) {
        boolean wasLoadSuccessful = loadX64ResourcesFromSysPath();
        if (!wasLoadSuccessful) {
            wasLoadSuccessful = loadWin32ResourcesFromSysPath();
            if (!wasLoadSuccessful) {
                setLibDirectory();

                wasLoadSuccessful = copyAndLoadX64FromTemp();
                if (!wasLoadSuccessful) {
                    wasLoadSuccessful = copyAndLoadWin32FromTemp();
                    if (!wasLoadSuccessful) {
                        throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError("Could Not Load myo and myo-java libs");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Your Operating System is not supported at this time.");
    }
}

private void setLibDirectory() {
    try {
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", TEMP_DIRECTORY_LOCATION.getAbsolutePath());
        Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
        fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
        fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private boolean loadX64ResourcesFromSysPath() throws UnsatisfiedLinkError {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("myo64");
        System.loadLibrary("JNIJavaMyoLib");
        return true;
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        String errorMessage = String.format("Unable to load myo64 from system directories.");
        System.err.println(errorMessage);
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean copyAndLoadX64FromTemp() {
    try {
        File myo64DllTempFile = new File(TEMP_DIRECTORY_LOCATION, "myo64.dll");
        myo64DllTempFile.deleteOnExit();
        try (InputStream myo64DllInputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/x64/myo64.dll")) {
            Files.copy(myo64DllInputStream, myo64DllTempFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

        File jniJavaMyoLibDllTempFile = new File(TEMP_DIRECTORY_LOCATION, "JNIJavaMyoLib64.dll");
        jniJavaMyoLibDllTempFile.deleteOnExit();
        try (InputStream jniJavaMyoLibDllInputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/x64/JNIJavaMyoLib.dll")) {
            Files.copy(jniJavaMyoLibDllInputStream, jniJavaMyoLibDllTempFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

        System.loadLibrary("myo64");
        System.loadLibrary("JNIJavaMyoLib64");
        return true;
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        String errorMessage = String.format("Unable to load %s from directory %s.", "myo64.dll", TEMP_DIRECTORY_LOCATION);
        System.err.println(errorMessage);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Error messages:

During first trying to connect with device:

```
Unable to load myo64 from system directories.
Unable to load myo32 from system directories.
```

During second trying to connect with device:

```
Unable to load myo64 from system directories.
Unable to load myo32 from system directories.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Anka\AppData\Local    \Temp\myo64.dll
at   sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:3004)
at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.copyAndLoadX64FromTemp(Hub.java:184)
at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.loadJniResources(Hub.java:67)
at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.<init>(Hub.java:27)
at pl.pollub.controller.device.DeviceTask$2.call(DeviceTask.java:54)
at pl.pollub.controller.device.DeviceTask$2.call(DeviceTask.java:49)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at pl.pollub.controller.device.DeviceTask$1.call(DeviceTask.java:31)
at pl.pollub.controller.device.DeviceTask$1.call(DeviceTask.java:27)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Unable to load myo32.dll from directory C:\Users\Anka\AppData\Local\Temp.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Anka\AppData\Local\Temp\myo32.dll:  Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.copyAndLoadWin32FromTemp(Hub.java:222)
at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.loadJniResources(Hub.java:69)
at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.<init>(Hub.java:27)
at pl.pollub.controller.device.DeviceTask$2.call(DeviceTask.java:54)
at pl.pollub.controller.device.DeviceTask$2.call(DeviceTask.java:49)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at pl.pollub.controller.device.DeviceTask$1.call(DeviceTask.java:31)
at pl.pollub.controller.device.DeviceTask$1.call(DeviceTask.java:27)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The error message implies that you try to load an `IA-32bit` dll, whereas you are running on an `AMD-64bit`-system. Are you sure you have the correct version of the `dll`-file?

Comment: Yes, I have included all version dll (x64, x32 and for mac). I have also tried manually delete and locate them in temp path - it doesn't give any results.

Comment: Could you - instead of print a simpile error message - print the wohle stack trace of the thrown exception in method `copyAndLoadX64FromTemp()`? I have a feeling that the file the system is trying to load cannot be found.

Comment: This is something I've got from other project. I can't change method in project above, as it's inn final class .java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no myo64 in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
 at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.loadX64ResourcesFromSysPath(Hub.java:157)
 at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.loadJniResources(Hub.java:61)
 at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.<init>(Hub.java:27)
 at com.thalmic.myo.example.HelloMyo.main(HelloMyo.java:16)

Comment: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no myo64 in java.library.path` - There you have it. There is not `myo64.dll` in the `java.library.path`. Therefore, you are missing the right `dll` or it has a different name.

Comment: To your original question: there are possibilities to modify final classes, but they deploy byte code manipulation. I would not recommend using them.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, and sorry for late reply. I have finally made it. You were right - I needed to add VM options. Question is solved. Thanks one more time!